# How to import a constant function from a file that is in the src folder in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, import

I have a react project with firebase and a form. This is my file hierarchy:

[image]

`firebase.js` contains an async function that returns a string:

```
export const addClient = async (object) => {
  if (object == {})return;
  const ref = await firestore.collection('clients').add({
    test: 'test',
    testtickle: 'test-tickle'
  })
  return ref; 
}
```

How do I import this function from `Form.js`?

This is my `Form.js` file:

```
import {addClient} from '.../firebase';
export default class Form extends React.Component {
  ...
  async handleSubmit(event) {
     ...
      addClient({
         test: 'test'
      })
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '.../firebase' in 'C:\Users\brandon pillay\Documents\react_projects\transformation\src\Components\Clients'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should go out two folder:

```js
import {addClient} from '../../firebase';
```